# IAM Policy to restrict one type of instances to Ec2-classic only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I am trying to restrict launch of c1.medium instance only for EC2-classic. My requirement is:

- c1.medium can not be launched in VPC
- c1.medium can only be launched in ec2-classic
- No restriction on other types of instances.

To achieve, I make use of ec2:InstaceType and ec2:vpc condition element. I created following policy and attached it to user

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnEqualsIfExists": {
                "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/vpc-*"
            },
            "Null":{
                "ec2:vpc" : "true"
             },
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceType": [
                    "c1.medium"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

One another policy is attached which provides user ec2:*. 
Above policy should work. In my opinion ec2:vpc should return False when instance is launched in Ec2-classic making condition block logic false.

But I am not seeing above behaviour. Its blocking for both vpc and Ec2-classic

Comment: Can you share why you want to prevent users launching c1.medium instances in VPC?

Comment: @jarmod I want to block launching of 3rd generation instances in VPC in my final prod AWS account. Just for testing I pick c1.medium. I can replace it with regex later. We dont need G3 instances but have some legacy in classic

Comment: The provided policy isn't actually a valid JSON policy. Please correct and re-post.

Comment: @jarmod policy updated